# transactions have not been committed or rolled back

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9, mysql-error-1064, mage

I am try to import the data using a custom script.I have tried below 3 ways:

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");
$write->insert("my_table", array("title" => 'test', "page_title" => 'test');
```

second way

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (title, page_title) VALUES ('test', 'test')";
$write->query($sql);
```

third way

```
$customModel = Mage::getModel('my module model alias');
$customModel->setTitle('test');
$customModel->setPageTitle('test');
//$customModel->setData('title','test');
//$customModel->setData('page_title','test');

$result = $customModel->save();
```

In all ways I got the

```
ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4040
```

Please suggest How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Code which you have provided is not sufficient to understand the error. Please provide full code of your script. As per you error - transaction somewhere started is neither commited nor rolledback, this means, somewhere an error is thrown which stops the code to process the rollback() or commit().

Comment: Its a custom script at root folder

Comment: add try{ /*stuff*/ }catch(Exception $e){ Mage::logException($e);} and check exception.log in var directory. If you found any exception post here to check the issue. And @rajatsaurastri is right about the issue.

Comment: I will recommend you to enable query log & check which query is failing. Also put your code into try catch block and print the exception message.

Comment: I have already tried the try catch and also print on log file, its the same error as posted above in question.